# Quick way to remove surrounding backet/parenthese/block in Visual Studio 2010 + Resharper ? (Reverse surround with)

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there something that can do reverse "surround with"?

From:

`((Type)myobject);`

To:

`(Type)myobject;`

From:

`if/while/try/using... {

    lots of code here....

}`

To:

`lots of code here....`

Answer (score 1):

Try structural search and replace (see [JetBrains .NET tools blog](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/tag/structural-search-and-replace/), [JetBrains TV](http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/using-search-with-pattern-to-change-old-style-assertareequal-to-new-style-assertthat) for additional guidance)

For your first example, you can use the following pair of patterns:

Search pattern: `(($type$) $var$)`
Replace pattern: `($type$) $var$`

where `$type$` is a type placeholder, and and `$var$` is an identifier placeholder.

To play a bit more with structural search and replace, you might want to download a [sample SSR pattern catalog](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/PublicPatternCatalog.zip) from ReSharper web site

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom replace patterns

- of answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329870/1187616 (Remove
  enclosing braces) for removing any curly braces and
- of answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329722/1187616 (Remove if envelop) for removing surrounding if by one shrtcut.